# how to kill a process on devops (ideally with a timeout)

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I have a complex devops build script in yaml.  Is there some way that if a given step takes too much time the process is killed (or some task is executes which kills certain processed).

This is would be useful in our case where we have large tests suites in several DLLs.  I am seeing often that some tests fail and after devops hangs.  I would like to kill the testrunner and other processes which may be hanging with (and also without) a timeout.

Is this possible on devops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `timeoutInMinutes` and `cancelTimeoutInMinutes` for the job:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: Test
  timeoutInMinutes: 10 # how long to run the job before automatically cancelling
  cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 2 # how much time to give 'run always even if cancelled tasks' before stopping them
```

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#timeouts